# Voltage Loss - Light Switch Gap

Tags: electrical, wiring

I’ve got a simple monopole light switch setup. With the light switch removed, I measured 100 V across the line wire and load wire (would expect 120 V).

If I measure across line and neutral or ground, I get 120 V.

The neutrals are twisted together, so I took the cap off and touched the voltmeter tip to each neutral wire to make sure their contact was good. I got 120 V both times, so I think the neutrals are good.

So this 20 V loss seems to just be a black wire thing. The light bulb is downstream of where I’m measuring, so not sure what could be the cause?

Comment: Is it a LED light bulb? If so that could explain your voltage loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this answer in Electrical Engineering stack exchange. It explains it nicely.
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/187461/voltage-drop-across-led-in-open-circuit

Comment: The link provided was very helpful in understanding what was going on. My lightbulb is fluorescent, not LED. But the main takeaway is still that the nature of the load (eg type of lightbulb) can affect the voltage reading. I tested out an incandescent bulb, and the voltage was 120 V.

Answer (score 0):

Don't test hot to load voltage.  Your volt meter is required to be connected parallel to the circuit, never in series.

Comment: Well measuring the voltage across a battery is really a series circuit.

Comment: @itchmyback If you close a circuit by placing a light bulb in line with a volt meter then it is a series circuit.  If you expect to measure battery voltage in this configuration you will be disappointed every time.  The resistance of a light bulb is not zero and therefore the potential across the series connected meter must always be less than the battery or line or whatever you thought you were going to measure by connecting it wrong.